# Download and store file on iphone

Tags: iphone, download

i want to replace my sqlite DB stores on iphone by a sqlite which is on my server for an update.
how could i do that? i can download it and get it with an NSData object but how do i store it on the iphone and then replace the old one ?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty simple. It should just be something like this:

```
NSData *fetchedData = ...;    /* downloaded using NSURLConnection or whatever*/
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DBName.sqlite"];

[fetchedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```